# How can I turn `file` tool into a predicate for `find`?

Tags: command-line, find

I have something like:

```
find . -type f -print0  | xargs -0 file | grep Matroska | cut -d: -f 1-1 | xargs rm
```

I want something like:

```
find . -type -f -filemagic "Matroska" -delete
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-exec` indeed can be used as a predicate. `find(1)`:

```
Execute command; true if 0 status is returned.
```

So this example would be:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'file "$0" | grep -q Matroska' '{}' ';' -and -delete
```

Obviously, instead of `-delete` there can be `-ls` or `-print0` or more predicates.

Answer (score 3):

You can run `bash` inside `find` with `-exec` option and run `file` inside shell, e.g.:

```
find . -type f -execdir bash -c 'file "$0" | grep -q Matroska && rm "$0"' {} \;
```

Comment: Can I exec `file` in `find` and use it's return code for further find program?

Comment: @Vi. I don't think so, at least I can't see the clear way.

Comment: Yes, it can. See my own answer.

Comment: @Vi. OK, just one remark - it is better to use `execdir` instead of `exec`, see: http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Race-Conditions-with-_002dexec.html